# integrate 0 to 2 $(5+\sqrt{(2x+x^2)})$

Tags: calculus, integration

integrate from $\int_0^2(5+\sqrt{(2x+x^2)})$

my process. 
$\int_0^25dx+\int_0^2\sqrt{(2x+x^2)})$
$=10+\int_0^2\sqrt{(2x+x^2)})$

I get confused the second integral though:
$y^2=2x+x^2$
$y^2=2x+x^2+1-1$
$y^2=(x+1)^2-1$
$y^2-(x+1)^2=-1$

...I don't understand how to compute the area from this or if this is even helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're on the right track. We can rewrite the second integral as:

$$\int_0^2 \sqrt{(x+1)^2-1}\ dx$$

and we can use a simple substitution to turn this into

$$\int_1^3 \sqrt{y^2-1}\ dy$$

We now note that

$$\tan^2 \theta + 1 = \sec^2 \theta$$

and so we want to use the substitution

$$y = \sec \theta, dy = \tan \theta \sec \theta d\theta$$

and get

$$\int_{\arccos(1)}^{\arccos\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)} \tan^2 \theta \sec \theta \ d\theta$$

Write $\tan^2 \theta$ as $\sec^2 \theta -1$:

$$\int_{0}^{\arccos\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)} \sec^3 \theta - \sec \theta\ d\theta$$

This can be evaluated by a [nice reduction formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_reduction_formulae#Transcendental_functions):

$$\int \sec^n \theta\ d\theta = \frac{\sin \theta \sec^{n-1} \theta}{n-1} + \frac{n-2}{n-1} \int \sec^{n-2}\theta\ d\theta$$

Which gives that

$$\int \sec^3 \theta\ d\theta = \frac{\sin \theta}{2\cos^2 \theta} + \frac{1}{2} \int \sec \theta\ d\theta$$

So our integral becomes

$$\frac{\sin \theta}{2\cos^2 \theta}\bigg|_0^{\arccos\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)}-\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\arccos\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)} \sec \theta\ d\theta$$

Since it is well known that

$$\int \sec \theta d\theta = \log\left|\tan(\theta) + \sec(\theta)\right|+C$$

the integral becomes

$$\frac{\sin \theta}{2\cos^2 \theta} - \frac{1}{2}\log\left|\tan(\theta) + \sec(\theta)\right|\bigg|_0^{\arccos\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)}$$

At $\theta=0$ this is just $0$, and at $\theta = \arccos\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)$ it equals

$$\frac{\frac{2\sqrt{2}}{3}}{\frac{2}{9}} - \frac{1}{2}\log\left|2\sqrt{2}+3\right| = 3\sqrt{2} - \frac{1}{2}\log\left|2\sqrt{2}+3\right|$$

which is the value of the integral. Adding to

$$\int_0^2 5\ dx = 10$$

we get the value

$$10+3\sqrt{2} - \frac{1}{2}\log\left|2\sqrt{2}+3\right| = 10+3\sqrt{2} - \sinh^{-1}(1)$$

the final result.

Answer (score 0):

It suffices to compute 
$$
I=\int_0^2 \sqrt{2x+x^2}dx=\int_0^2 \sqrt{(x+1)^2-1}dx
$$
Let $y=x+1$, we have
$$
I=\int_1^3\sqrt{y^2-1}dy=\frac{1}{2}y\sqrt{y^2-1}-\frac{1}{2}\ln(y+\sqrt{y^2-1})\bigg|_1^3=3\sqrt{2}-\frac{1}{2}\ln(3+2\sqrt{2})
$$
The formula we use here can be found in integral gormula table.